# Authflow gets changed when I call initiateAuth in 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'

Tags: amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-identity-js

I am trying to call initiateAuth method using authflow "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH" but in the request I get "CUSTOM_AUTH". Why is this happening and how to resolve this issue?

Screenshots of my code:
1)
[image]

2)
[image]

3)
[image]